# Django AJAX Request Fails To Send

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, tastypie

I'm trying to make an AJAX POST request to create a new object. I have a Tastypie API that I would like to handle the request.

Here is my code.

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('#newpersonalitem').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {name: $('#name').val()};
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://162.216.18.30:8000/api/v1/personalitem/'
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id='newpersonalitem'>
{% csrf_token %}
New Item: <input type='text' id='name'>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form the pages reloads and but the request is never sent. I have tested the API and I am able to successful make this same request from a mobile app. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:
I've since tried adding the recommended changes here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

and I added `{% csrf_token %}` in the `<form>`.

Still with no luck.

Comment: why do you have a `preventDefault` on `$(document).ready(function` ? No listeners are getting created.

Comment: That has since been removed, forgot to update the question. Its correct now. Am I correct in putting the submit listener inside the `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes you are. One more issue: `$('#name').val().serialize()` is invalid. If you only want to send the `name`, try `data = {name: $('#name').val()}` and send this as `data: data`

Comment: I tried that with no change. I also tried something else I found which I've updated in the question but did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit), i realy like it.

Maybe this works:

```
<form action="http://162.216.18.30:8000/api/v1/personalitem/" id='newpersonalitem'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    New Item: <input type='text' id='name'>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event) {      
       var options = { 
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               location.reload();
           }
       };

        $('#newpersonalitem').submit(function (event) {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference.

Comment: instead of using `submit` function, use `on('submit', function(event){...})` ??

Comment: Still getting no response.