# CURL Request to Tastypie API Returns Nothing

Tags: ajax, django, curl, tastypie

I have a Tastypie API written for a mobile app to communicate with my Django backend. For this purpose it functions properly, however I would like to use it to make AJAX requests as well. I tried diving right into the JS, writing a form to be submitted by an AJAX POST request. This seemed to do nothing except refresh the page when you click submit. You can find my JS and HTML here:

[Django AJAX Request Fails To Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477222/django-ajax-request-fails-to-send)

Having reached no solution there, I tried going backwards and accomplishing the same requests with CURL.

`curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name" : "apples"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/item/` simply hangs and never returns anything. I have to use `CTRL+C` to escape in the shell.

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

I've installed POSTMAN and used it to try and make the request. This returned a `500 Internal Server Error`with this error message:

``` "The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on your Serializer." ```

UPDATE II:

In POSTMAN I've tried sending data in a variety of encoding formats, however every different encoding option returned a `no deserialization method` error except `application/json`. When I sent `{name:'apples'}` encoded this way it returned an error:

`"Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"`

Comment: Why don't you try setting it up in [POSTMAN](http://getpostman.com) to see if you can send your POST? It will generate a proper CURL command to test as well; if you can, then you know your issue is JS-side. If you can't, you know it's server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've installed POSTMAN and put the results of using it in my question.

Comment: Looks like you're sending it with the wrong encoding type. Try RAW / JSON

Comment: I updated my question after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of -H, try with -d, It simply posts data...

`curl -d "info posted on to the server" http://ur ip address`

`-H`will always give you header information and `-d` it directly post data in server

Comment: By the looks of things, that's exactly what he's trying to do. How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Actually -d sends specified data in POST request to server. Its like browsing our internet, Whereas -H is extra header while browsing internet.. You have a look at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html to see documentation

Comment: He's setting the header with -H, sending post data with (-d|--data).

Comment: But I think -H doesn't follows POST approach.. I am not that much sure about it..

Comment: That curl command was copied directly from the Tastypie documentation. Could this really be the cause of the issue?

Comment: @haye321: Can't say.. At least you can give a try.. Well n good if it works, otherwise somebody will post or answer it..

Comment: OK, I'm inclined to believe it's on the server side then. Not knowing what is going on on the back-end, I can't say what kind of request it's expecting. Maybe not even JSON at all? Xml?

Answer (score 0):

What is the return code? There is no such thing as "does not return anything". Run `curl` with `-v`: `curl -v --dump-header ...` to see more information. You can also look at your server logs or at the console of the Django development server to see if there is even a request coming in.

> "The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available
>   deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and
>   `content_types` on your Serializer."

Try passing an explicit `Accept` header with

```
-H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
```

Also disable the CSRF middleware (and all other middleware that you can disable), and see if it helps.

Then, what is your authentication method? Api key? Session? Basic authentication? Chances are that you are getting the 401 error. In order to see if it gets to the authorization point, take the `UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization` class from [Tastypie docs on authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html), use it as your authorization class, and insert `print` statements in every function.

Lastly, here is a working example with HTTP PUT:

```
curl -v --dump-header -  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X PUT "https://website.com/api/v1/3/?username=<user>&api_key=<api_key>"  --data '{"apple": "banana"}'
```